# Animate a line into a sine wave in iOS

Tags: ios, animation

I'm new to animation in iOS and there seems to be a lot of different ways to accomplish the same thing. I'm looking for a way to animate a flat line into a sine wave and back. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Also how would I go about adding an ease out or bounce effect?

Comment: see this for reference:  https://github.com/joericioppo/Shape_04

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `CAShapeLayer` (with `UIBezierPath`s to specify your line and sine wave line) and `CABasicAnimation` to achieve this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.fromValue = (id)linePath;
animation.toValue = (id)sinePath;
[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
```